# Why AsyncTask crashes when switching Fragment, but not in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Most probably I am missing some basics here, if anybody can point out please.

If I run an AsyncTask in an activity and then switch to another Activity, the AsyncTask runs in background without any issue.

But now that I have one Activity and different Fragments which I loads through a Navigation drawer, my AsyncTasks (intiated in Fragments) crashes whenever I switch to another Fragment.

Searching in SO, it seems like this is expected behavior, but can you please tell me why? What I saw from tracing, if I destroy current Fragment and load a new one, AsynTask crashes in the line contains getActivity().

My Code:

Activity:

```
public class MyContainer extends Activity {
.........................
public void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentB();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentC();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawer);
        }
    }
 }
```

**Fragment A:**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    ...................
    ...................
    private class RemoteConnectivity extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String>
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        int mId;
        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Import/Export")
            .setContentText("In progress")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... args) {
            mId = 1;
            ..................
            try 
            {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                String[] dataline;
                mylibmandbhandler db = new mylibmandbhandler(getActivity());
                int maxlength = jArray.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < maxlength; i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    cnt = 0;
                    dataline = new String[19];
                    dataline[cnt++] = json.getString("xxxxxx");
                        ......................
                        ......................
                    dataline[cnt++] = json.getString("yyyyy");
                        db.addRecord(new mylibman(dataline));
                    mBuilder.setProgress(maxlength, tot, false);
                    mNotifyManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
                }
                db.close();
            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                return " E503: Error parsing data.";
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result1) 
        {
        mBuilder.setContentText("Completed. "+result1).setProgress(0,0,false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
            ((MyContainer)getActivity()).updateCount();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355): Process: com.migrationdesk.mylibman, PID: 2355
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at com.migrationdesk.mylibman.ImportExportFragment$RemoteConnectivity.onPostExecute(ImportExportFragment.java:554)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at com.migrationdesk.mylibman.ImportExportFragment$RemoteConnectivity.onPostExecute(ImportExportFragment.java:1)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-02 05:21:00.935: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are doing some ui work on post execute of your asynctask at line 554 in ImportExportFragment.java and that produce null pointer exception so try check your ui element alive or not

Comment: NPE is located here: "onPostExecute(ImportExportFragment.java:554)" show onPostExecute code

Comment: thanks ... I had issue in doinbackground as well where I called getActivity ... I just declared Context context = getActivity() in PreExecute method, and used context hereafter ...